# Can stereo rectification always succeed given R and T

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

Given R and T between two cameras, the function StereoRectify from OpenCV is called to perform camera rectification to align the two image planes. Does this can always succeed no matter how large the angles between two cameras calculated from R using function Rodrigues? I hope to learn the principle of camera rectification. Any introductory paper or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the same problem. From the algebraic viewpoint, the image rectification is achieved by applying 2D projective transformations (or homographies) on pair of images whose epipolar geometry is known so that epipolar lines in the original images map to horizontally aligned lines in the transformed images.

So StereoRectify is the process by which two images of the same solid scene undergo homographic transforms, so that their corresponding epipolar lines coincide and become parallel to the x-axis of image. There always should be Rotation and Translation that can allow rectification process but due to the redundant degrees of freedom, the solution to stereo-rectification is not unique and actually can lead to undesirable distortions or be stuck in a local minimum of the distortion function.

I have [tested a stereo platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341953/how-does-parameters-impact-on-rectification-process) with two cameras and I used a different poses( R and T). When I obtained a good calibration parameters I was always able to find a good rectification images. The size of output images strongly depends on overlapping view from cameras and distortion parameters. 
However it should restricts the search domain for each match to a line parallel to the x-axis but in practice, it was sometime even a few of lines.

Some of interesting papers:

1. [Computing rectifying homographies for stereo vision](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/786928/)
2. [Essential and fundamental matrices, their computation, RANSAC algorithm, rectication](http://imagine.enpc.fr/~monasse/PSL/PSLITI2.pdf)
3. [Epipolar rectification](http://www.diegm.uniud.it/fusiello/demo/rect/)
4. [Image Rectification (Stereo)](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS6320-S2013/Materials/CS6320-CV-F2012-Rectification.pdf)