# How does parameters impact on rectification process?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, geometry, image-rotation

Why does rectification work like this? Please can someone explain me it in details? How does extrinsic parameter affect rectification result?

1) I build the set of stereo cameras where I can rotate them as I want to. My input images:
[image: input image]
2) I calibrated them using [Matlab](http://mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-camera-calibrator-app.html) and confirmed by [Kalibr](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr) method. So I assume that I know perfect intrinsic, distortion and extrinsic parameters.

3) I implemented rectification based on openCV 2.4.13 and Matlab as reference. My translation express in meters [0.13 0.003 0.003].  My rectified images:

[image: perfect translation]

4) However I would like to understand the impact of translation parameters. I started experiments with different values. I notice that when I set a translation between cameras to vector [0, 0 ,0] image was a little bit wider in range but has the same size ( we may see a little bit more on the top of image) image below:
[image: where translation is 0]

5) When I changed translation on [2 0.5 0.2]

[image: nice try trtanslation]

6) When I changed translation on [140 3 3] so in scale of millimeters. It seems show that the scale factor has not big impact on rectification process. I think that in depth analyses it will has a big impact.

[image: scale millimeters]

For all of images alpha parameter was equal 0. The openCV results are close to Matlab functions from the similar functionality (image below).

[image]

Finally could someone explain me how the translation and rotation (extrinsic) parameters implicate on rectification process and correct this epipolar geometry? Below is the way that I implemented my program and some of my remarks.

I checked some literature but still I didn't find clear answer:

[A compact algorithm for rectification of stereo pairs](http://www.diegm.uniud.it/fusiello/papers/00120016.pdf)

[Szeliski's book page 538](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf)

I initialize all parameters:

```
parameters = cv::Mat::zeros(height1, width1, CV_64FC1); parameters.at<double>(0,0) = fx;
```

First - I found important issues that all parameters have to be **double**. Second - that nb 1 refereed to camera right which is express in left frame camera coordinates.
I call the:

```
C++: void stereoRectify(InputArray cameraMatrix1, InputArray distCoeffs1, InputArray cameraMatrix2, InputArray distCoeffs2, Size imageSize, InputArray R, InputArray T, OutputArray R1, OutputArray R2, OutputArray P1, OutputArray P2, OutputArray Q, int flags=CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, double alpha=-1, Size newImageSize=Size(), Rect* validPixROI1=0, Rect* validPixROI2=0 )
```

I played with all parameters. After:

```
C++: void initUndistortRectifyMap(InputArray cameraMatrix, InputArray distCoeffs, InputArray R, InputArray newCameraMatrix, Size size, int m1type, OutputArray map1, OutputArray map2)
```

I remap:

```
C++: void remap(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray map1, InputArray map2, int interpolation, int borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=Scalar())
```

Finally my program looks very similar to [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7240). [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) is documentation to openCV.

For Matlab:

```
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);
```

Thanks for your time and answers. Regards.